# \\machinename cannot open network share while \\ipaddress work in cross domain

Tags: domain-name-system, network-share, windows-server-2019, trust-relationship

We have established a two-way trusted domain environment. All servers are Windows Server 2019. In server1.domainA.com there is shared drive. In server2.domainB.com, we tried to browse with \\server1 it prompt for access denied. But it works for \\server1.domainA.com or \\IPaddress.

On server2, "ping server1" resolve to correct IP. The result is same as "ping server1.domainA.com".

We checked conditional forwarder is setup on both domain's DNS already.

What could be the issue and how to troubleshoot?